# Confusion with Closure in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code.

```
<body>

<p>Counting with a local variable.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>

<p id="demo">0</p>

<script>
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
</script>
</body>
```

> The variable add is assigned the return value of a self invoking
>   function.

Does this mean, every time add is called,only return of function is invoked not the whole function ?

If not,Can anyone please explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, only the returned function inside the IIFE is called when the `add()` function is called.

The IIFE is called on pageload <s>when the parser encounters it</s> during the execution phase, and returns the other function as a reference to be called later.

The only thing the outer IIFE is doing is keeping the `counter` variable inside it's own scope.

IIFE == [Immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Comment: Why isn't the code executing from the first statement of the function but rather jumps to return directly.Please can you give me some explanation.

Comment: The outer function is an IIFE, it's immediately invoked when the parser encounters it, and the result is returned, which in this case is another function.

Comment: I think the wikipedia page I linked to explains it pretty well.

Comment: Yes, only the returned function inside the IIFE is called when the add() function is called. In this statement when you say `return` is called.The return is of outer function not inner function. right?

Comment: Actually not "*when the parser encounters it*" but later, during the execution phase. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the following code, you have a function that returns a function:

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {
        return counter += 1;
    }
})();
```

The outer function is immediately executed.  So, `add` is assigned to the inner function:

```
function () {
    return counter += 1;
}
```

As you can see, the `counter` variable in the inner function refers to the *context* of the outer function (where `counter` is declared).  This *context* is called `closure` and is still referenced in the inner function.  So, JavaScript keeps this context alive.

As **@RobG** points out, the internal JavaScript execution rules are more like: the identifier `counter` in the inner function is first resolved in the inner execution context. Since it isn't found there, the next object on the scope chain is searched, which is the outer execution context and `counter` is found there.

So, by the magic of closure, the `counter` variable can still be accessed and changed when calling the inner function (using `add`).

So, when calling `add`, you are executing the inner function, which is closing over `counter`.

Comment: A more extensive explanation might be: "the identifier *counter* in the inner function is first resolved in the inner execution context. Since it isn't found there, the next object on the scope chain is searched, which is the outer execution context and *counter* is found there". But maybe that's just me. ;-)

Comment: @RobG  That is a more extensive explanation.  I've added it to the answer. thx.